# Airflow unable to identify errors - SSHHook

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, amazon-emr

I have spun up an EMR cluster and I am running a spark job on it via Airflow's SSH Hook.
When I manually run the spark job (using spark-submit) on the EMR master node, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/movie_data_analysis.py", line 37, in <module>
    movies = movies.rdd.map(lambda x: [int(x["_c0"].split("::")[0]),x["_c0"].split("::")[1]]).toDF(["movie_id","title","genre"])
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 58, in toDF
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 746, in createDataFrame
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 395, in _createFromRDD
IndexError: list index out of range
22/06/19 10:59:58 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
22/06/19 10:59:58 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Interrupting monitor thread
22/06/19 10:59:58 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
22/06/19 10:59:58 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
22/06/19 10:59:58 INFO SchedulerExtensionServices: Stopping SchedulerExtensionServices
(serviceOption=None,
 services=List(),
 started=false)
22/06/19 10:59:58 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
22/06/19 10:59:59 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
22/06/19 10:59:59 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
22/06/19 10:59:59 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
22/06/19 10:59:59 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
22/06/19 10:59:59 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
22/06/19 10:59:59 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
22/06/19 10:59:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/06/19 10:59:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-...
22/06/19 10:59:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-...
3
22/06/19 10:59:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-...
```

But when I run this command using Airflow's SSH hook, it does not show the failure status on this task and rest of the down stream tasks are executed.

How do I handle these errors?

Comment: How do you run the command using Airflow's SSH hook? Is it calling `exec_ssh_client_command`? If so, `exec_ssh_client_command` returns a tuple of `(exit_status, agg_stdout, agg_stderr)` which you can inspect to determine if an error occurred and handle it accordingly. 

Do the downstream tasks depend on the SparkJob completing successfully? If yes, you may want to add a  `depends_on` constraint on the operation(s) directly downstream from it.

Comment: it suggests there's an error in your pyspark code. please look into that, and we can help you debug that if you post the code here.